# node-mysql query results as nested array (without column names)

Tags: node-mysql

I'm using node-mysql to query my database but it is returning an array with objects like :

```
[{"col1":1, "col2":2}, {"col1":3, "col2":4},{"col1":5, "col2":6}...]
```

What I'd like it to return is a simple nested array without column names as follows :

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]...]
```

Is this possible with node-mysql?